# How to toggle class to child only of current clicked class

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to toggle a class for an element when a parent class is clicked, but since it's a menu where most classes are the same I don't want to toggle all children with that class, only the child of of the parent that is currently clicked.

My html structure:

```
<li>
    <a href="">Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</a>
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus-box menuicon dropdown"></i>
    <ul class="dropdown-content menuliststyle">
        <li>Algemene bedrijfsgegevens</li>
        <li>Organogram</li>
        <li>Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then in my footer I got the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".menuicon").on("click", ".dropdown-content" function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("dropdown-show");
       console.log('test');
    });
});
```

So I want to fire the function when `.menuicon` is clicked but only toggle the class for its current child.

I also tried this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".menuicon > dropdown-content").on("click", function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("dropdown-show");
       console.log('test');
    });
});
```

But I am not even seeing test in my console, so what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `.menuicon > dropdown-content` cant work as that selector would select a element `dropdown-content` as direct child of `.menuicon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to fire the function when .menuicon

In that case target the .menuicon class,.  And looking at your HTML, you then want the next sibling,.. in jquery this is `next`..

eg.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".menuicon", 
    function() {
       $(this).next().toggleClass("dropdown-show");
    });
});
```

```css
.menuicon {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content.dropdown-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="">Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</a>
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus-box menuicon dropdown">▼</i>
    <ul class="dropdown-content menuliststyle">
        <li>Algemene bedrijfsgegevens</li>
        <li>Organogram</li>
        <li>Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="">Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</a>
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus-box menuicon dropdown">▼</i>
    <ul class="dropdown-content menuliststyle">
        <li>Algemene bedrijfsgegevens</li>
        <li>Organogram</li>
        <li>Toepassingsgebied managementsysteem</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```